# API request - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, json, api, request, get

I develop a simple API request. Here is the code:

```py
import requests
import json

#Get data
result = requests.get("https://pkip.riga.lv/documentregistration/divisionregister?district_id=516&division_id=2863")
divisions = json.loads(result.content)
info_list = []

for info in divisions:
    info_list.append(info["valid_from"])
print (info_list)

div_list = list(dict.fromkeys(info_list))

#Sort
div_list.sort()

#Print
for info in div_list:
    print(info)
```

The actual problem is, that I can not get any response. It gives an error message:

```py
info_list.append(info["valid_from"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I have checked the request link syntax and it is correct. Here you can see the translated documentation, because it was not in English:

Data on institutions, their identification, hierarchy of institutions, periods of activity of institutions and specifics of document numbering.

Data fields:

number - Serial number of the record in the dataset

district_id - Municipality

request_date_time - Date and time of retrieval

division_id - Institution identifier

division_title - Name of the institution

managing_division_id - Managing authority identifier

managing_division_title - Name of the managing authority

is_managing_unit - Flag indicating that the institution is the managing

use_own_document_numbers - Indication that institutions use their own document numbering

number_prefix - The designation used in the institution's document registration number

valid_from - The date on which the institution started

valid_to - The date on which the institution ceases to exist

updated - Date and time of the last correction

Comment: to me `info` is a string. have you checked that is a dict or you just assume so despite the message?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code to look what went wrong when transforming your data from the API request, the thing that you are doing is you want to get "valid_from" from your request but the field "valid_from" is under

```
- districts
    -divisions
         -valid_from
```

so instead of trying to get valid from from districts itself you need to go to the right path of the field in json

i updated your for loop, it might still not be perfect but it should fix your problem

```
for info in divisions["districts"]:
    for div in info["divisions"]:
        info_list.append(div["valid_from"])
print(info_list)
```

I hope this fixes your problem!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You can open URLs like yours in a browser (I use Firefox, but Chrome should have a usable JSON view, too) to have a decent JSON viewer to inspect the response with.

Also consider looking into [ipython or jupyther](https://ipython.org/). Either will enable you to run your steps interactively, and investigate the values you're working with as you are modifying them.

---

When you play around with this you will notice that the `divisions`-field is another array you will have to iterate over to get the `valid_from`-values from. That can look something like this:

```py
info_list = []
for district in divisions["districts"]:
    for division in district["divisions"]:
        info_list.append(division["valid_from"])
print(info_list)
```

---

Lastly, your last operation sorting the values in your `info_list` can be done immediately on that list. Your `dict.fromkeys`-step is effectively not doing much. Consider dropping `div_list` entirely and sorting and displaying `info_list` instead.